# Variance Estimator Change if we know Population Mean? (Normal dist. example)

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, estimation, estimators, point-estimation

For a normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ a commonly used unbiased and consistent estimator of variance is

$$\hat \sigma^2=\frac{\sum_ix_i^2 + n(\bar x)^2}{n-1}=\frac{\sum_i(x_i-\bar x)^2}{n-1}$$

However, suppose we know the population (true) mean, should the estimator be adjusted to reflect that, meaning should my estimator instead be:

$$\hat \sigma^2=\frac{\sum_ix_i^2 + n(\mu)^2}{n-1}=\frac{\sum_i(x_i-\mu)^2}{n-1}$$

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your estimated variance in the case where the population mean $\mu$ is known, has
the wrong denominator (if it is to be unbiased). The correct denominator of the unbiased estimate $\hat{\sigma^2}$ of $\sigma^2$ is especially easy to verify in the case of normal data.

To begin, $Z_i = \frac{X_i -\mu}{\sigma} \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$
So, $Q_i = Z_i^2 = \frac{(X_i - \mu)^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=1)$
and $Q = \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(X_i - \mu)^2}{\sigma^2}
\sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n),$ which has $E(Q) = n.$

Thus (upon multiplying by $\sigma^2/n)$ we have $V =\hat{\sigma^2} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2$ has
$E\left(\hat{\sigma^2}\right) = \sigma^2.$

In the (most common) case where data are normal and $\mu$ is *unknown* (estimated by $\bar X),$ the relationship
$\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n-1),$
where $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2,$ is important
for making confidence intervals for $\sigma^2$ and testing hypotheses about $\sigma^2.$

Similarly, when data are normal and $\mu$ is *known ,* the relationship
$\frac{nV}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n)$
is important
for making confidence intervals for $\sigma^2$ and testing hypotheses about $\sigma^2.$

Comment: But then this means that the use of the true parameter $$\mu$$ has led to a minor reduction in estimator variance (practically no difference if n is very large)

Comment: Knowing $\mu$ is useful information, and additional  information often reduces variance. Somewhat similarly, if $\sigma$ is known and $\mu$ is not, then a z confidence interval is used to estimate $\mu.$ However, if $\sigma^2$ is also unknown and estimated by $S^2,$ then the (wider) t confidence interval is used for $\mu.$